# django manage.py reported a fatal error: Python/modsupport.c:91 object at 0xb63f0e2c has negative ref count -1246818113

Tags: django, python-2.7

django version: 1.10.3,

python version: 2.7.12,

[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2,

i updated the python from version 2.6 to 2.7.12, there is no problem in the progress of python installation. 
unfortunately when i run command "python manage.py makemigrations show", there is a fatal error occoured.

```
inf@inf:/opt/lampp/htdocs/dpcm$ python manage.py makemigrations show
Fatal Python error: Python/modsupport.c:91 object at 0xb63b1e2c has negative 
ref count -1247076161
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried python commands and run other scripts, this will won't happen. what's wrong with this?? Anybody know?

Comment: have you tried deleting pyc files?

Comment: project? it's not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i found the root cause: there is conflict between python2.7.6 and 2.7.12.
just need to remove the old lib,